# How to use python to talk about the numbers in four arrays for limited extraction data combination?

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from itertools import combinations
import pandas as pd

num = ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09']

for data in combinations(num, 6):
    red_ball1 = data[0]
    red_ball2 = data[1]
    red_ball3 = data[2]
    red_ball4 = data[3]
    red_ball5 = data[4]
    red_ball6 = data[5]
    values=(str(red_ball1),str(red_ball2),str(red_ball3),str(red_ball4),str(red_ball5),str(red_ball6))
    print (values)
    print (',')
```

If I have four four groups

```
a:[01,02,03,04]
b:[06,07,08,09,17,18,19]
c:[01]
d:[02,03,04,05,07,08,12]
```

I need to extract numbers from four groups of data to form a new group with only seven numbers.

The new 7-digit array contains all the contents of A and C arrays each time,

- A and B form the first five data of the array,
- C and D form the last two data of the array.

Comment: If I have four four groups
a:[01,02,03,04]
b:[06,07,08,09,17,18,19]
c:[01]
d:[02,03,04,05,07,08,12]

Comment: I need to extract numbers from four groups of data to form a new group withs only seven numbers
The new 7-digit array contains all the contents of A and C arrays each time
A and b form the first five data of the array
C and d form the last two data of the array

Comment: For example, the array I want to get：
x1:[01,02,03,04,06],[01,02]
x2:[01,02,03,04,07],[01,03]
x3:[01,02,03,04,08],[01,04]
......xn
Exhausting all combinations

Comment: it would be simpler to display `print(data)`. Besides, list `num` has only strings and they don't need `str()`

Comment: it seems you can reduce it to one problem `A and B  form the first five data of the array`, because `C and D` is similar problem but with different data. IF you will know how to do it for `A and B` then you will know also how to do it for `C and D`. And if you need data from all list then `C and D` is even simpler because `C` has only one value - so this value has be alwasy in last two digits - and you have to only select one value from `D`

Comment: If `A and B` has to create 5 digits and you have to have valus from A and B then first you have to use `A` to create number which has at least 1 digit and at most 4 digits (to have place for at least one digit from `B`), and later you have to add missing digits from `B`

Comment: it may need nested `for`-loops: first use A to generate all 1-digit items and use it with all 4-digits items generated from `B`. Next use A to generate all 2-digits items and use it with all 3-digits items generated from `B`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can reduce it to one problem `A and B form the first five data of the array`, because `C and D` is similar problem but with different data.

If you will know how to do it for `A and B` then you will know also how to do it for `C and D`.

And if you need data from all list then `C and D` is even simpler because `C` has only one value - so this value has be always in last two digits and you have to only select one value from `D`

---

If `A and B` has to create 5 digits and you have to use at least one value from `A` and at least one value from `B` then first you have to use `A` to create items with 1 digit and use `B` to create items with 4 digits, next the same for 2 digits from A and 3 digits from B, next the same for 3 digits from A and 2 digits from B, and next the same for 4 digits from A and 1 digit from B.

So it may need nested `for`-loops. First select number of digits in `A`, (and `5-number` of digits in `B`), next nested `for`-loop to generate lists with `number digits` using `A`, and next nested `for`-loop to generate lists with `5-number digits` using `B`

Something like this:

```
from itertools import combinations

A = ["01","02","03","04"]
B = ["06","07","08","09","17","18","19"]

for number in range(1, 5):
    print(f"--- {number}A + {5-number}B ---")
    for a in combinations(A, number):
        for b in combinations(B, 5-number):
            print(a + b)  # join two lists
            # ... here generate numbers from `C and D`
```

Result:

```
--- 1A + 4B ---
# ... many values ...
--- 2A + 3B ---
# ... many values ...
--- 3A + 2B ---
# ... many values ...
--- 4A + 1B ---
('01', '02', '03', '04', '06')
('01', '02', '03', '04', '07')
('01', '02', '03', '04', '08')
('01', '02', '03', '04', '09')
('01', '02', '03', '04', '17')
('01', '02', '03', '04', '18')
('01', '02', '03', '04', '19')
```

---

**EDIT:**

if list `A` or `B` can be shorter than `4` then it may need `if` to check it and skip code

```
if (number > len(A)) or (5-number > len(B)):
   contiune # skip code
```

---

**EDIT:**

Full code:

```
from itertools import combinations

A = ["01","02","03","04"]
B = ["06","07","08","09","17","18","19"]
C = ["01"]
D = ["02","03","04","05","07","08","12"]

results = []

for number1 in range(1, 5):
    print(f"--- {number1}A + {5-number1}B ---")
    
    if number1 > len(A) or 5-number1 > len(B):
        print('skip')
        continue
    
    for a in combinations(A, number1):
        for b in combinations(B, 5-number1):
            #print(a + b)

            for number2 in range(1, 2):
                print(f"--- {number2}C + {2-number2}D ---")
                
                if number2 > len(C) or 2-number2 > len(D):
                    print('skip')
                    continue

                for c in combinations(C, number2):
                    for d in combinations(D, 2-number2):
                        print(a + b + c + d)
                        #results.append(a + b + c + d)
```

---

**EDIT:**

If digits can be in any order then it will need more `for`-loops.